# How to deploy Realm Object Server on Google Cloud

Tags: realm, google-cloud-platform

I am planning to use Realm Mobile Platform for my project and wish to deploy the realm object server on Google Cloud.

As mentioned on [link](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/), there is no direct one click solution for it.

So I need to create an instance on Google Cloud with the supported Operating System like CentOS 7 and install realm object server there and deploy it.
Or there is another approach.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any immediate plans to support one-click installs on the Google Cloud platform. You're welcome to create a feature request regarding this in our [public issue tracker](https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues), as I don't think there is one for this yet.

We currently support AWS AMIs, CentOS 6 & 7 (binary compatible with RHEL), and Ubuntu 16.04.